# БД и приложение социальной сети с правами пользователя

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, mongodb, angular

Хочу написать социальную сеть свою. Для практики полезно.
Есть очень много вопросов связанных преимущественно с БД.
Какую или какие бд выбрать для хранения данных. Как хранить разные данные там(просто id или имя пользователя например понятно, а вот с правами пользователя, лайками, сообщениями и т д не очень понятно)?
Ладно если это сущность пользователь. Пойдет mysql. А сообщения, посты, картинки и т д... Какую БД выбрать? или нужна пара бд.

Нужны права доступа для пользователей. в какой бд их хранить и в каком виде(там ключ - значение и тд или как...)

В какой последовательности разрабатывать такое приложение. Я начинающий java программист. Эту прилагу решил написать на Angular. Бэк энд пока нз на чем писать буду, либо на java либо на Nodejs...Скорее всего попробую на NodeJs

буду рад если подробно ответите, не знаю с чего начать честно говоря... Немешало бы с базы начать, но по ней куча вопросов...
Про различия sql и noSql читал, но какую выбрать или в какой что хранить пока нз как правильно разобраться

До написания вопроса смотрел много статей на оверфлоу и в нэте примерные схемы. Но там только схемы и зачастую всеравно не то.

Comment: Берите и делайте на том, что нравится. Будут проблемы - перепишите. Это же проект для себя,

Comment: Думаю мой вопрос несет пользу, т к многие сталкиваются с этим вопросом на первых парах. Поэтому посоветуйте чтото дельное. Бери и делай - ок, принимаю. Можно еще чтото дельное, я же не просто так задал вопрос чтоб его минусовали или придерались. Да, на инглише тоже гуглил. Думаю это не сложно ответить, а не минусануть и свалить...

Comment: Не только вы задавались таким вопросом https://qna.habr.com/q/143677
Это не простой вопрос так же например как я хочу создать автомобиль, помогите с чего начать )

Comment: В крупных социальных сетях одной БД никак не обойтись.